# Where can I find the constant definition of LANG_HINDI?

Tags: delphi, multilingual, delphi-xe3

I am writing a Delphi program which will use Hindi. I use Soluling which produce .RC files with constant LANG_HINDI.

But it is not recognized as a valid constant.

I try to search all source files including Windows.pas, but cannot find its definition. Also with Visual Studio source codes, there is also no such a constant.

Where is LANG_HINDI defined?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the missing constants.

```
  // Language ids that are not defined in Delphi's Windows unit
  LANG_ALSATIAN_C = $84;
  LANG_AMHARIC_C = $5e;
  LANG_ARMENIAN_C = $2b;
  LANG_ASSAMESE_C = $4d;
  LANG_AZERI_C = $2c;
  LANG_BANGLA_C = $45;
  LANG_BASHKIR_C = $6d;
  LANG_BENGALI_C = $45;
  LANG_BRETON_C = $7e;
  LANG_BOSNIAN_C = $1a;
  LANG_CORSICAN_C = $83;
  LANG_CENTRAL_KURDISH_C = $92;
  LANG_CHEROKEE_C = $5c;
  LANG_DARI_C = $8c;
  LANG_DIVEHI_C = $65;
  LANG_FILIPINO_C = $64;
  LANG_FRISIAN_C = $62;
  LANG_FULAH_C = $67;
  LANG_GALICIAN_C = $56;
  LANG_GEORGIAN_C = $37;
  LANG_GREENLANDIC_C = $6f;
  LANG_GUJARATI_C = $47;
  LANG_HAUSA_C = $68;
  LANG_HINDI_C = $39;
  LANG_IGBO_C = $70;
  LANG_INUKTITUT_C = $5d;
  LANG_IRISH_C = $3c;
  LANG_KANNADA_C = $4b;
  LANG_KASHMIRI_C = $60;
  LANG_KAZAK_C = $3f;
  LANG_KHMER_C = $53;
  LANG_KICHE_C = $86;
  LANG_KINYARWANDA_C = $87;
  LANG_KONKANI_C = $57;
  LANG_KYRGYZ_C = $40;
  LANG_LAO_C = $54;
  LANG_LOWER_SORBIAN_C = $2e;
  LANG_LUXEMBOURGISH_C = $6e;
  LANG_MACEDONIAN_C = $2f;
  LANG_MALAY_C = $3e;
  LANG_MALAYALAM_C = $4c;
  LANG_MALTESE_C = $3a;
  LANG_MANIPURI_C = $58;
  LANG_MAORI_C = $81;
  LANG_MAPUDUNGUN_C = $7a;
  LANG_MARATHI_C = $4e;
  LANG_MOHAWK_C = $7c;
  LANG_MONGOLIAN_C = $50;
  LANG_NEPALI_C = $61;
  LANG_OCCITAN_C = $82;
  LANG_ORIYA_C = $48;
  LANG_ODIA_C = $48;
  LANG_PASHTO_C = $63;
  LANG_PERSIAN_C = $29;
  LANG_PUNJABI_C = $46;
  LANG_QUECHUA_C = $6b;
  LANG_ROMANSH_C = $17;
  LANG_SAKHA_C = $85;
  LANG_SAMI_C = $3b;
  LANG_SANSKRIT_C = $4f;
  LANG_SINDHI_C = $59;
  LANG_SINHALESE_C = $5b;
  LANG_SCOTTISH_GAELIC_C = $91;
  LANG_SOTHO_C = $6c;
  LANG_SWAHILI_C = $41;
  LANG_SYRIAC_C = $5a;
  LANG_TAJIK_C = $28;
  LANG_TAMAZIGHT_C = $5f;
  LANG_TAMIL_C = $49;
  LANG_TATAR_C = $44;
  LANG_TELUGU_C = $4a;
  LANG_TIBETAN_C = $51;
  LANG_TIGRINYA_C = $73;
  LANG_TSWANA_C = $32;
  LANG_TURKMEN_C = $42;
  LANG_UIGHUR_C = $80;
  LANG_UPPER_SORBIAN_C = $2e;
  LANG_VALENCIAN_C = $03;
  LANG_URDU_C = $20;
  LANG_UZBEK_C = $43;
  LANG_WELSH_C = $52;
  LANG_WOLOF_C = $88;
  LANG_XHOSA_C = $34;
  LANG_YAKUT_C = $85;
  LANG_YI_C = $78;
  LANG_YORUBA_C = $6a;
  LANG_ZULU_C = $35;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Soluling supports told me the contants come from the Windows Kit header files, like below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ntdef.h
```

So I need to import these constants to Delphi manually.

Comment: Unfortunately Delphi's Winapi.Windows.pas does not contain all the LANG_xxx constants. Embarcadero should update the file to contains the values from ntdef.h.